# Why filter on a lazy sequence doesn't work in clojure?

Tags: clojure

I am hoping to generate all the multiples of two less than 10 using the following code

```
(filter #(< % 10) (iterate (partial + 2) 2))
```

Expected output:

```
(2 4 6 8)
```

However, for some reason repl just doesn't give any output?

But, the below code works just fine...

```
(filter #(< % 10) '(2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16))
```

I understand one is lazy sequence and one is a regular sequence. That's the reason. But how can I overcome this issue if I wish to filter all the number less than 10 from a lazy sequence...?

Comment: There are simpler endless futile searches: `(some neg? (range))`, for instance. In your example, it's the attempt to realise the fifth element that never returns. Wrap your expression in `(take 4 ... )` and you get `(2 4 6 8)`.

Answer (score 10):

```
(iterate (partial + 2) 2)
```

is an infinite sequence. `filter` has no way to know that the number of items for which the predicate is true is finite, so it will keep going forever when you're realizing the sequence (see Mark's answer).

What you want is:

```
(take-while #(< % 10) (iterate (partial + 2) 2))
```

Answer (score 6):

I think I should note that [Diego Basch's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26009745/3687048) is not fully correct in its argumentation:

> `filter` has no way to know that the number of items for which the predicate is true is finite, so it will keep going forever

Why should `filter` know something about that? Actually `filter` works fine in this case. One can apply `filter` on a lazy sequence and get another lazy sequence that represent *potentially* infinite sequence of filtered numbers:

```
user> (def my-seq (iterate (partial + 2) 2)) ; REPL won't be able to print this
;; => #'user/my-seq
user> (def filtered (filter #(< % 10) my-seq)) ; filter it without problems
;; => #'user/filtered
user>
```

Crucial detail here is that one should never try to realize (by printing in OP's case) lazy sequence when actual sequence is not finite for sure (so that Clojure knows that).

Of course, this example is only for demonstration purposes, you should use `take-while` here, not `filter`.

Comment: exactly. The caveat here is printing the resulting sequence, which forces realization.

Comment: I agree, I should have said that realizing the sequence enough to provide results will take forever. Obviously `(take 4 (filter ...)` returns instantly.